# How to combine 8 data frames into one GGplot (or anything)

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have 8 data frames (one of each for years 2007-2014), all set up the same, only difference being the numbers:

[image: one data frame]

I need to show a graph with market share on y axis, year on x axis, and all 7 regions shown per year. How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: Trying adding a column for year and the stack/row bind the datasets together.

Comment: @aosmith how do i add a column for year?

Comment: I don't know what your set-up looks like, but it can be as simple as `dat$year = 2007` for a 2007 dataset named `dat`. R takes care of making the new column and then recycling the value for you.

Comment: Thanks, years added. How do I combine them to stack now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
A = rbindlist(list(data_table_1,...,data_table_n),use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

then do something like

```
ggplot(data = A) + geom_bar(aes(x = year, y = MarketShare, fill = Region),stat = 'identity')
```

That could work I guess

Comment: I get this error msg "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (52): x, y, fill"

Comment: @JoeJohnson Use the rbindlist to stack them, and try to find some information about ggplot yourself. Learn how to debug code and try to understand it, the error message itself is quite clear to be honest. I can give you some hints, but you learn more from your own mistakes